# Memory Leak with Service Implements Interface

Tags: android, memory-leaks

Lets say you have a `Service` class that implements an interface (let's call it `SomeInterface`), and another class has a static `SomeInterface` variable that is referring to that `Service`. Can this produce a memory leak? I am assuming so but I'm not 100% sure.

EDIT: The code I have inherited appears to have a sample of this class:
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/pythonforandroid/bootstraps/pygame/build/src/org/renpy/android/billing/BillingService.java

Take note of the `private IMarketBillingService mService;`
Well in the code I have inherited it is `private static IMarketBillingService mService;`

Comment: Can you post a code sample?

Comment: Yes - don't do this

Comment: @barq I made an edit to my post

Comment: @PPartisan my assumption is that once the service connection is terminated, since that variable is static we are still holding on to the reference of the other service, in which case it can't be garbage collected.